# How to write a flag to a 7-bit number

Tags: javascript, integer, bit-manipulation

Along the lines of [How to read off 1 flag bit and get integer at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045509/how-to-read-off-1-flag-bit-and-get-integer-at-same-time/52045580#52045580), wondering how to do the reverse, of writing a flag to the right side of a 7-bit number in JavaScript.

I assume we are just using integers in JavaScript, and have checks in the code to make sure the number < 128. So given that, wondering how to basically say:

```
 var flag = true
 var integer = 123
 var combined = integer + flag
```

Comment: Why don't you use the << operator? Take a look: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the combined number by bitshifting the integer and adding the flag.

```
const combined = (integer << 1) + flag
```

That will suffice, and give you a number back. The parenthesis are necessary due to the order of operations.

Comment: Note that this assumes the 123 is a number you want _in addition to_ the flag. If that's not the case, a simple bitwise or will work.

Comment: Yes I just want to take an integer and append a flag to it, whatever the integer is. So I think this is correct. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Given you linked to another post, I presume you're able to undo this operation to get the flag and number back out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) to achieve this

```js
var flag = true;
var integer = 123;
console.log((integer >>> 0) + flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

On `123` the rightmost bit is already set. If you want to set the rightmost bit, just add one. Or you can `integer | flag ? 1 : 0` to the integer.

If you want to put on a flag on the right, shift the the integer left with `integer << 1` and then `var combined = integer | flag ? 1 : 0`